# How to resolve KeyError when user inputs an element that does not exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## partial code

```
if password_Dictionary[username] == password:
    print("Allow!\n")
    break
else:
    print("Wrong!\n")
```

## error

```
if password_Dictionary[username] == password:
KeyError: 'cskmcdsk'
```

## explanation

If the user inputs a username but not the correct password`enter code here` the program correctly runs a print statement that states user inputted wrong password, but when the user inputs an incorrect username/one that does not exist, it raises that 'KeyError' with 'cskmcdsk' being the random username the user tried inputting but it does not exist.

## question

How would I stop the coding from causing an error and instead continue running and instead print an output that states that username is not in the dictionary?

Comment: you can use --> " if username in password_Dictionary " to check is this key available in the dictionary. if it returns false. then provide that key error

Comment: additionally you can wrap the "password_Dictionary[username] in a try except block, but you should only do this if it's an error, if this is an expected occurence, then Lucefer's answer is more apt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use a `try`/`except` block (exceptions are not for normal control flow). Instead, either check for the presence of the key in the dict, e.g.

```
if username in dictionary and dictionary[username] == password:
    # do stuff
```

or, alternatively, use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which will return `None`, or some default (be certain to choose a default value which will not also be the value of the other side of the `==`), e.g.

```
{}.get('notakey')         #=> None
{}.get('notakey', 'foo')  #=> 'foo'
```

As an aside, if you’re storing passwords, please ensure to use a strong one-way hash function (e.g. BCrypt).

Comment: @QRuns Well, did this answer your question? Don’t forget to [upvote/accept answers to your questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/158402) `:)`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use try catch block for the key error, so when there is an error , you can catch it and do whatever you want when you catch a `KeyError`.

Comment: No, you should use perfectly readable `.get(key, defaultvalue)`. `if key in dict:` rarely makes sense because you most likely were going to take out the value anyway too. using `KeyError` is just plain wrong, 4 lines minimum for what you could do in 1-2, while also adding unnecessary identation and making it less readable.